# Showing unmanaged package type

Tags: package

While packaging App, it shows Package Type option read only and its default value is unmanaged. I am struggling to create managed package. What can be wrong to get unmanaged package type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Managed Packages](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/enabling_managed_packages.htm) can only be created in Developer Edition orgs and require a [namespace](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/register_namespace_prefix.htm) to be registered.

You can create only one Managed Package per Dev Edition Org.

Comment: I am using developer edition. It says, I need to install License agreement app, but it is paid one.

Comment: Have you registered a namespace?

Comment: Yes, registering namespace allowed me to create managed package. Thanks!